# Memory leak when drawing lines in OpenGL3

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I'm having some memory leak issues with my draw line function.
I'm using windows task manager to see that there is a problem. When I start the application it uses around 200MB and after running it for around 10 mins it uses around 10GB (stops when I stop drawing lines).

My draw line function looks something like:

```cpp
static unsigned int buffer;
void drawLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    x1 = pixToPointWidth(x1, width);
    y1 = pixToPointHeight(y1, height);
    x2 = pixToPointWidth(x2, width);
    y2 = pixToPointHeight(y2, height);

    float pos[12] = {
        x1, y1, r, g, b, a,
        x2, y2, r, g, b, a
    };

    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pos), pos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 6, (const void*)8);

    if (!createdShader)
    {
        createShader();
    }

    glUseProgram(shader);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
}
```

It's getting called in a while(true) loop with 1ms sleep.

Comment: Admittedly not knowing a damn thing about OpenGL, I would find it unusual if that `glGenBuffers` call didn't ultimately require a mated `glDeleteBuffers` *somewhere* . If you're systematically only creating a shader on first-request, any particular reason you're not doing the same with your buffers?

Comment: Looks like this is what I needed. I wasn't aware of this. Thank you! Looking at it now it just fluctuates +- 20 MB :) I hope this is the right way to do it. Just added `glDeleteBuffers(1, &buffer);`after `glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);`

Comment: @MegaMagnum If this is just a test it's fine, but normally you should not create and delete the buffers on every frame. This is extremely inefficient. Set them up at the start and then reuse them on every frame.

Comment: @MichaelMahn exactly, that was why I suggested going the same route that was (apparently) done with the shader: create on first use and persist for reuse on each call. Thanks for the confirmation.